# CKeditor skipping or ignoring \r\n from source

Tags: ckeditor

Ive been a few weeks into figuring our why CKeditor is ignoring the format of the source text and putting everything into a single paragraphs. For example, I have a form used to input contact details into my database. The text would come in with something like this (with break lines):

```
Contact Name: John Doe
Phone number: 123-123-1234
Cell: 123-123-1234
```

But when CKEDITOR converts my text area to an inline editor it converts it into a single paragraph:

```
Contact Name: John Doe Phone number: 123-123-1234 Cell: 123-123-1234
```

So I finally figured out that CKeditor seems to be ignoring or skipping the /r/n break lines format from the source. So it puts everything into a single paragraph. How would I force CKEDITOR to reconize /r/n as a 
? Would there is a simple workaround to this? Is there maybe something I can do with the database?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the only solution out there is just going to your SQL database and replacing \r\n to 
 using the following query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET text_column = REPLACE(text_column, '\r\n', '<br />')
```

If anyone had any other solution please let me know this is the only way to fix that issue.